# [Vue warn]: Property or method is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

[image]

I'm trying to build a vue google map component using google maps and the plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps. I have installed the plugin using npm , and I've got in working when my googleMap.vue component:

-->

```
        <!-- :center="{lat: 30.08674842, lng: -97.29304982}" -->
        <GmapMap
        :center="{lat: latitude, lng: longitude}"
        :zoom="15"
        map-type-id="terrain"
        style="width: 500px; height: 300px"
      >

      </GmapMap>
      </span>
      </v-flex>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  var latitute = 30.08674842
  var longitude = -97.29304982
  import {
    gmapApi
  } from 'vue2-google-maps'
  export default {
    // name:'myMap'
    latitute:latitute,
    longitude:longitude,
   }
<
```

when I run this I get:

```
 ERROR  [Vue warn]: Property or method "longitude" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

How can I fix this?

edit:

I changed the script component to:

```
<script>
  var latitute = 30.08674842
  var longitude = -97.29304982
  import {
    gmapApi
  } from 'vue2-google-maps'
  export default {
    data() {
            console.log('im in data')

      return {
        latitute: latitute,
        longitude: longitude
      } // name:'myMap'
    }
  }
</script>
```

no change - I'm getting the same error

edit2:

[image]

I changed the data component as above , and you can see that it is being read in the devtolls console. still no change with restarted computer. any thoughts on what to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your properties reactive `data`:

```js
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            latitude: latitude,
            longitude: longitude
        }
    }
```

The object you're exporting is a Vue configuration object and only properties it recognises will have any effect. While it might be convenient to think of it as being like a class definition it really isn't. Unrecognised properties, like `latitude` and `longitude`, will just be discarded and won't end up as members of your component instances.

If you want something be available as `this.blah` you need to define `blah` as a prop, data property, computed property or method. Within the template the `this.` is implicit but the same rule applies.

**Update:** Corrected typo `latitute` which had been copied from the original code.

Comment: @user61629 This really should fix it. My guess would be that either you have a caching problem or you have another component with the same mistake. I suggest putting some console logging inside the `data` function to confirm that it is being called.

Comment: @user61629 The new error that you've posted is slightly different from the original error. Note that it references `latitude` rather than `longitude`. This is because `latitude` has been spelt incorrectly as `latitute`. You'll need to fix that typo wherever it appears in your code.